# Too much vertical space after section title

Tags: graphics, vertical-spacing

In a **book class** document (for some reason with article class the problem does not show up) I need to insert a section containing only images (an image gallery). Images are of various size and aspect ratio, but some code helps in sizing them automatically. Depending on images, the vertical space after section title may be too big. I guess the problem is that the space after the section title is stretched too much to avoid blank space at the end of the page. I tried without success to increment the vertical space before title and between “lines” (if I can call them so).

Here is a MWE. How can I increment the vertical space before title and between lines? I'm looking for a generic solution, not tailored on a certain combination of images.

Thanks in advance for any clue.

P.S. My actual document is compiled with XeLaTex, I hope this does not affect solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xfp}
% add to \includegraphics the option sqrtofarea that sizes image so that it has a given area, regardless of aspect ratio
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{sqrtofarea}{%
    \def\Gin@req@sizes{%
      \edef\Gin@scalex{\fpeval{#1/sqrt(\Gin@nat@height*\Gin@nat@width)}}%
      \let\Gin@scaley\Gin@exclamation
      \Gin@req@height\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@height
      \Gin@req@width\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@width
      }%
  \@tempswatrue}
\makeatother

% command helping to insert images in a photo gallery
%usage: \imageofgallery{image file}{square root of image area}{margins of image}
\newcommand{\imageofgallery}[3]{%
\begingroup\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{#3}\setbox0=\hbox{\fbox{\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=#2]{#1}}}\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup\hspace{1pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Image gallery}
\begin{center}
\newcommand{\imgsize}{12em} % images will be sized so they have an area of 12x12 sq-em, regardless of aspect ratio
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: book defaults to `\flushbottom` you probably want `\raggedbottom` so the extra space comes at the end of the page.

Comment: I guess I need `\flushbottom` for the rest of the book, which is an ordinary book containing mainly text.

Comment: you can force that page to finish short by using `\clearpage where you want the break

Comment: The problem is that the image gallery is 3-4 pages long, I have 8 image galleries, and I would like to avoid a solution tailored of the current images, in case of future image or paper size changes. I would prefer to add some "elastic vertical space" before title and between lines.

Comment: I just tried to compile with `\raggedbottom` but I get too much vertical space at the bottom of many pages.

Comment: just put`\raggedbottom` before that \section and go back to \flushbottom after all the images

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I will use that workaround if no better solution is given.

Comment: if you want flush bottom except for one section where you don't, then that isn't a "workaround" it's the intended markup.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course, for better solution I mean *"increment the vertical space before title and between lines"*, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the given code is that the bottom picture doesn't fit and is moved to the next page.

Issue `\raggedbottom` for the duration of the `center` environment, with a `\clearpage` at the end.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{xfp}
% add to \includegraphics the option sqrtofarea that sizes image
% so that it has a given area, regardless of aspect ratio
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{sqrtofarea}{%
    \def\Gin@req@sizes{%
      \edef\Gin@scalex{\fpeval{#1/sqrt(\Gin@nat@height*\Gin@nat@width)}}%
      \let\Gin@scaley\Gin@exclamation
      \Gin@req@height\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@height
      \Gin@req@width\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@width
      }%
  \@tempswatrue}
\makeatother

% command helping to insert images in a photo gallery
%usage: \imageofgallery{image file}{square root of image area}{margins of image}
\newcommand{\imageofgallery}[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{#3}%
  \sbox0{\fbox{\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=#2]{#1}}}%
  \parbox{\wd0}{\box0}%
  \endgroup
  \linebreak[0]%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Image gallery}
\begin{center}
\raggedbottom % this is local to center
\newcommand{\imgsize}{12em} % images will be sized so they have an area of 12x12 sq-em, regardless of aspect ratio
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-1x1}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-16x9}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\imageofgallery{example-image-10x16}{\imgsize}{1ex}
\clearpage
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I made a few small changes to the code: `\setbox0=\hbox` should be `\sbox0`; instead of `\hspace{1pt}` use `\linebreak[0]`, so no additional space is inserted, but a line break after each image is allowed nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the improvements to the auxiliary code. I'm accepting the answer, unless a way to *"increment the vertical space before title and between lines"* show up.