# What can cause large space before a section?

Tags: spacing

I am writing a book. In one of my sections in one of my chapters, there's a big vertical space before the next section as per below:

[image]

Usually the spacing is much smaller. It's probably the default one. I am using a stylesheet from my university but it looks like there's nothing related to section spacing in there. There was a '...' earlier, in that screenshot, in place of the 'etc'. I thought it could have caused the problem.

My .tex file otherwise contains nothing special in this area, it is just:

```
text
\section{Proposed Solution}
text
```

Comment: you presumably have `\flushbottom` and some large non-float at the top of the next page

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531659/too-much-vertical-space-after-section-title

Comment: Thanks. It's unclear from the link how I can set the option to raggedbottom though :(

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: you could put `\raggedbottom` in the preamble if you want ragged, or put `\clearpage` before whatever is on the next page but it is hard to tell you what to change if you show no relevant code.

Comment: Stop using figure [H} (or other large non-breakable boxes).