Sudden overspacing when editing document
I was editing my document, which has around 7 pages, I deleted a few lines of formulas on page 4, and the spacing of page 4 enlarged itself. The other pages were fine like as if it were normal. What is the reason and how do I fix it? Note that I did not use \pagebreak in the document.

I used the following packages
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}


After deleting certain codes and recompiling, I found out that the codes in page 5 caused the problem. The problem seems to stem in the following code
\[
\begin{split}
S_m&= H_{N+1}^{m}H_N-\sum_{n=1}^N H_n \Delta H_n^m \\ 
&= H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H^k_{n+1} H_n}{(n+1)^{m-k}}} \\ 
&= H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\right\} \\
&= H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\\  
&\approx H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-m)S_m +\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k}{m-k+1}\\ 
\implies (m+1)S_m &\approx H_{N+1}^{m+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=-1}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k+1}(-1)^{k+m+1}\pHz{k+1}{m-k} \\ 
&= H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-1)^{m+1} \zeta(m+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}{\underbrace{\left[\binom{m}{k}+\binom{m}{k+1}\right]}_{\textstyle \binom{m+1}{k+1}}}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}\\
\end{split}
\]

In terms of the defined command, only \pHz is relevant. I posted the same code on math stack exchange as one of my answers (Proof of Proposition 2). Confusingly, line 5 to 6 didn't align (I didn't think about it much at that time, now I presume that this is related to the error).

The following page shows over spacing


You should (always) provide an example but my guess would be \flushbottom is in effect see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531659/too-much-vertical-space-after-section-title

unrelated to vertical spacing (but you have not provided any code that shows the spacing problem) ams alignments should (almost always) use &= not =&

! Undefined control sequence. <argument> ...0}^{m-2}\binom {m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz 

How or where is \pHz defined?

Please replace all instances of = & and \approx & with &= and &\approx, respectively, in order to assure consistent alignment.

You have edited the question and added a lot of code but none of it useful to see the problem. You were lucky I could guess an answer but please always provide a complete example that shows the issue not just disconnected fragments of code

The screenshot and the math code you've posted do not appear to be related to each other.

@Mico I used = & instead of & = because for some equations that are too long I will break them apart and put the remaining equation to the second line. If I use &= the residual equation will start at the left-hand side of the "=" sign, which is not what I want. Using = & makes the equation start at the right-hand side of the equal sign, that solves the problem.

@Mico I never knew that the equation is not aligned, thank you for the reminder. Now as you have said, is there a way to solve my problem while keeping the alignment?

You did not provide any example that showed bad vertical spacing, but I would guess you have something like this

where you have \flushbottom in affect and some large unbreakable object at the top of the following page, so this page has to be stretched to flush the last line to the bottom.
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand\pHz{ph?}
\flushbottom
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
line one  
\end{center}


\begin{center}
line two
\end{center}




\[\begin{split}S_m= & H_{N+1}^{m}H_N-\sum_{n=1}^N H_n \Delta H_n^m \\ 
= &H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H^k_{n+1} H_n}{(n+1)^{m-k}}} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\right\} \\
 = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\\  \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-m)S_m +\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k}{m-k+1}\\ 
\implies (m+1)S_m \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=-1}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k+1}(-1)^{k+m+1}\pHz{k+1}{m-k} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-1)^{m+1} \zeta(m+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}{\underbrace{\left[\binom{m}{k}+\binom{m}{k+1}\right]}_{\textstyle \binom{m+1}{k+1}}}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}\\
\end{split}\]


\[\begin{split}S_m= & H_{N+1}^{m}H_N-\sum_{n=1}^N H_n \Delta H_n^m \\ 
= &H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H^k_{n+1} H_n}{(n+1)^{m-k}}} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\right\} \\
 = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\\  \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-m)S_m +\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k}{m-k+1}\\ 
\implies (m+1)S_m \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=-1}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k+1}(-1)^{k+m+1}\pHz{k+1}{m-k} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-1)^{m+1} \zeta(m+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}{\underbrace{\left[\binom{m}{k}+\binom{m}{k+1}\right]}_{\textstyle \binom{m+1}{k+1}}}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}\\
= &H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{H^k_{n+1} H_n}{(n+1)^{m-k}}} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\right\} \\
 = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}-\frac{H^m_{N+1}}{N+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^{k+1}}{n^{m-k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1} \frac{H_n^k}{n^{m-k+1}}\\  \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-m)S_m +\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m}{k}(-1)^{m-k}\pHz{k}{m-k+1}\\ 
\implies (m+1)S_m \approx & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} \binom{m}{k}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}-\sum_{k=-1}^{m-2}\binom{m}{k+1}(-1)^{k+m+1}\pHz{k+1}{m-k} \\ = & H_{N+1}^{m+1}+(-1)^{m+1} \zeta(m+1)+\sum_{k=0}^{m-2}{\underbrace{\left[\binom{m}{k}+\binom{m}{k+1}\right]}_{\textstyle \binom{m+1}{k+1}}}(-1)^{k+m}\pHz{k+1}{m-k}\\
\end{split}\]

\end{document}

To avoid the issue you can use \raggedbottom or re-word to better fill the page, or allow the item to break (\allowdisplaybreaks if the item on the next page is display environment) or allow the large item to float as a figure or table (which is the reason latex has floats)

Thank you very much, it was because of the \begin{split}\end{split}. I need to use \allowdisplaybreaks and \begin{align*}\end{align*} instead
